# Problemas ao abrir e fechar arquivo com o fwrite

Tags: php, txt

Bom dia Pessoal! Estou com um problema na parte de reabrir um arquivo em TxT, o problema que na primeira instrução o mesmo abre normalmente, escreve e fecha. Porém mais abaixo no script tento reabrir o arquivo novamente e mesmo não abre, tao pouco escreve nele e retorna o seguinte erro.

> Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in
>   F:\wamp64\www\nfe\functions.php on line 70 Warning: fclose() expects
>   parameter 1 to be resource, string given in
>   F:\wamp64\www\nfe\functions.php on line 71

Segue o Codigo:

```
    $pasta = $data[0].$data[1].$data[2]."_".$data_end[0].$data_end[1].$data_end[2]; 
    foreach($config->empresas as $cfg){
            $txt = fopen("sintegra/SINTEGRA_".$pasta.".txt", "w");
            fwrite($txt,
                str_pad($cfg -> reg1, 2," ", STR_PAD_RIGHT).
                str_pad($cfg -> cnpj, 14," ", STR_PAD_RIGHT).
                str_pad($cfg -> ie, 14," ", STR_PAD_RIGHT).
                str_pad($cfg -> rsocial, 35," ", STR_PAD_RIGHT).
                str_pad($cfg -> municipio, 30," ", STR_PAD_RIGHT).
                str_pad($cfg -> uf, 2," ", STR_PAD_RIGHT).
                str_pad($cfg -> fone, 10," ", STR_PAD_RIGHT).
                str_pad($data[2].$data[1].$data[0], 8, " ", STR_PAD_RIGHT).
                str_pad($data_end[2].$data_end[1].$data_end[0], 8, " ", STR_PAD_RIGHT).
                str_pad($cfg -> lreg, 3," ", STR_PAD_RIGHT).
                "\r\n".
                str_pad($cfg -> reg2, 2," ", STR_PAD_RIGHT).
                str_pad($cfg -> endereco, 34," ", STR_PAD_RIGHT).
                str_pad($cfg -> numero, 5,"0", STR_PAD_LEFT).
                str_pad($cfg -> comp, 22," ", STR_PAD_RIGHT).
                str_pad($cfg -> bairro, 15," ", STR_PAD_RIGHT).
                str_pad($cfg -> cep, 8," ", STR_PAD_RIGHT).
                str_pad($cfg -> responsavel, 28," ", STR_PAD_RIGHT).
                str_pad($cfg -> fone, 12,"0", STR_PAD_LEFT)
                );
            fclose($txt);
        }

//APENAS TESTE//
    $g_txt = "sintegra/SINTEGRA_".$pasta.".txt";
    fopen($g_txt, "a+");
    fwrite($g_txt, "aqui ficara o conteudo!");
    fclose($g_txt);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na primeira vez que você abriu o arquivo, veja que você atribuiu à função um nome:

```
$txt = fopen(...
```

Em seguida escreveu e fechou usando esse nome:

```
fwrite($txt...
fclose($txt);
```

Logo, o erro se dá porque você está usando a string `$g_txt` como parâmetro da função. Você deve fazer como fez na primeira vez, atribuir um nome à função e usar esse nome para escrever/fechar o arquivo:

```
$g_txt = "sintegra/SINTEGRA_".$pasta.".txt";
$txt = fopen($g_txt, "a+");
fwrite($txt, "aqui ficara o conteudo!");
fclose($txt);
```

Comment: Obrigado meu amigo... não tinha me atendado a esse detalhe... mais foi de grande ajuda.

Comment: Obg amigo! Desejo çuçeçu! :D

Answer (score 4):

Isso acontece pois o parâmetro que as funções `fwrite()` e `fclose()` aceitam é a referência do arquivo aberto `fopen()` e não a string a ser inserida no arquivo `$g_txt` :

```
 $g_txt = "sintegra/SINTEGRA_".$pasta.".txt";
 $fp = fopen($g_txt, "a+");
 fwrite($fp, "aqui ficara o conteudo!");
 fclose($fp);
```